# Div not visible in IE8/7... sometimes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having a strange issue that I haven't encountered before.

I'm working on the front-end code for this page: REDACTED

When I view this in IE, the dropdown div doesn't show up (I currently have it set to show always while I troubleshoot, so it's that big block that has lists of Men's and Women's categories). I can click that div in IE Dev Tools and see its outline, but the div itself is nowhere to be found.

In the process of troubleshooting, I dumped my code into jsFiddle to mess around a little and there it works fine, while in IE. It's the exact same HTML and I just loaded my external CSS and JS files as resources, so it's all completely identical.

Here's the jsFiddle link: REDACTED

Anybody have any idea what gives?

Here's the CSS for the affected div:

```
#productDrop {
    background: url(../../images/global/bgProductDrop.png) no-repeat;
    left: -646px;
    height: 166px;
    padding: 40px;
    top: 37px;
    width: 675px;
}
```

Thanks much in advance,
Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `ie.css` delete the `overflow-x:hidden;` for the `#headerWrapper`